# Bind DisplayMemberPath to a function in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, function, binding, formatting

Is there a way I can bind the `DisplayMemberPath` of combobox to a function?  The object with which I am currently working has three properties I wish to use for presentation; `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `MiddleName`.

I wrote a static method in a Formatting class to handle it.  This method is called `FullName` and accepts three string arguments.

Is there a way I can call `Formatting.FullName` and pass in the three arguments from my `Person` object in order to display the formatted full name into the combobox items?

I've added the following XAML to the resources section of my page:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type business:Formatting}" x:Key="formatter" />

<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource formatter}" 
                    MethodName="FullName" 
                    x:Key="nameFormatter">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <system:String>Bloggs</system:String>
        <system:String>Joe</system:String>
        <system:String>Q</system:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

And my combobox XAML now looks like this:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Width="120" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Margin="467,72,0,0" 
          Name="cboDistrictAttorney" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding DistrictAttorneyId}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Source={StaticResource nameFormatter}}" />
```

And the end result is that I have a combobox full of blank items.

Answer (score 0):

Another case is DataTemplate, but DataTemplate is more heavier for your application.